# Excel formula for separating certain strings when it has a variety of text

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a bunch of data where I'm looking to pull all "sample1:" and any letters that come immediately after it. I'm not sure if the best way is to separate all of the sample1's from the rest of the strings in the cells or what. But basically, "sample1:" could have multiple letters following it, and it could come at the beginning, middle or end of the string. I've attached a screenshot of the data format - for example, I want to pull everything that comes after sample1: and before the ; (ex. sample1:A,B,C;sample3:20 would only pull "sample1:A,B,C")

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one has Excel O365, you could use `LET()`, e.g:

```
=LET(X,SEARCH("sample1:",A2),Y,SEARCH(";",A2&";",X),MID(A2,X+8,Y-X-8))
```

In case of Excel 2013 or higher, you could use `FILTERXML()`, e.g:

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,":",";"),";","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[preceding::*[1]='sample1']")
```

In (AFAIK) all versions of Excel, you could keep using `SEARCH()`:

```
=MID(A2,SEARCH("sample1:",A2)+8,SEARCH(";",A2&";",SEARCH("sample1:",A2))-SEARCH("sample1:",A2)-8)
```

---

[image]

---

If you need to keep "sample1" in there:

```
=LET(X,SEARCH("sample1:",A2),Y,SEARCH(";",A2&";",X),MID(A2,X,Y-X))
```

Or:

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A2,";","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[starts-with(.,'sample1:')]")
```

Or:

```
=MID(A2,SEARCH("sample1:",A2),SEARCH(";",A2&";",SEARCH("sample1:",A2))-SEARCH("sample1:",A2))
```

Comment: Thank you! But if I'm hoping to keep the sample1 intact with all of the A,B,C letters, would these still work? Also, this is going to apply for >1000 rows, so would like to have a robust solution where I don't need to count the number of integers to add/subtract to get the start of the "string1"

Comment: What is not robust about these solutions? Either way, what you want is easy to do. Just tinker around with the formulas to keep the sample1 text

Comment: `LEN("sample:1")` can be used instead of the hard coded 8...if I read and understood the formulas correctly

Comment: Thanks for showing that LET function. Never seen this before, but makes trimming text a whole less complicated.

Comment: @ForwardEd, I've just removed the -8 really. Will work just fine then.

Comment: @user14618570, you'r welcome, though remember it's exclusive to ExcelO365 at the moment (and Excel Online).